# How to set multivalued parameter to Select All when given specific values to the parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Hi I have a multivalued parameter 'location' in which i am specifying values in parameter like 'Dallas','Chicago','Seattle'.how can i set the default value to 'Select ALL' I know how to make if values are from query,but how can i make all of them default when values are specified.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

below link might be helpful for your approach.

http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2013/12/18/the-select-all-parameter-option-ssrs/

Answer (score 0):

Right click Parameter > Properties > Default values and Use the same method you used to provide 'Available values' for that same parameter, so either specify values or use query.
Hope this helps.

Wojtek